# Why are my awk results different from the example?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I'm learning awk and when I try the sample code [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Constant-Size) (gnu.org awk User's Guide, section 4.6), I get different answers for some of the lines.

Specifically, if the 'idle' column is empty (6 spaces), the script is pulling in data from the next 'non-empty' column (i.e. the 'JCPU' column). Also the 'idle' column is being skipped when it should be trying to convert '15days' to seconds (the awk is picking the next column for it's 'idle' value).

I'm trying to figure out why my awk results don't match the example's results.
I have ensured that my column widths match those in the FIELDWIDTHS parameter.
I am running on 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

My results are:

```
    hzuo    ttyV0   9
    hzang   ttyV3   50
    eklye   ttyV5   7
    dportein    ttyV6   107
    gierd   ttyD3   1
    dave    ttyD4   4
    brent   ttyp0   286
    dave    ttyq4   46
```

Comment: Try `awk -v` to see if you really are using GNU awk. FIELDWIDTHS is a GNU extension.

Comment: I'm not. I am actually running:

mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996, Copyright (C) Michael D. Brennan - 

I guess I just have to chalk this up to differences between mawk and awk!?

Comment: :-) Actually to the differences between `gawk` and `not gawk`. Happy awking - it's a great tool.

Comment: @Steve mawk is a minimally featured awk optimized for speed of execution. Get gawk.

Comment: You are so right - I was just looking at the mawk manual and it is very minimal. I just installed gawk. Its no surprise that now my code works perfectly! Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by Mark Setchell there are several versions of awk. In the Wikipedia entry for the tool you can read about the a few of them under History and also under Versions and implementations headings. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK)

```
awk -W version
```

[lets you know which version you are currently using in some variants of awk.](https://superuser.com/questions/646919/how-can-i-find-my-awk-version)
[You can also read the quite extensive manual of gawk to find out more about the tool.](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html)

Your problem is probably an attribute to differences in the implementations of the different versions.

Comment: I just installed gawk (running awk was actually running mawk). Its no surprise that now my code works perfectly! Thanks for your help!!